# Object doesn't return the maximum number - JS

Tags: javascript, object

I was trying to return the maximum repeated word. However for some reason it doesn't return the max. Here's the code responsible for that:

```
var max = -Infinity;
        for(var prop in myObj){
          if(myObj[prop] > max){
            max = prop;
          }
        }
       return max;
```

This one returns "h" w/c is the first element in the word 'helllo'...it supposed to be 'l'...

Right now here's my whole codes:

```
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word) {
  var splitWord = word.split('');
 var myObj = {};
 for(var i = 0; i < splitWord.length; i++){
   if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(splitWord[i])){
     myObj[splitWord[i]]++;
   }else{
     myObj[splitWord[i]] = 1;
   }
 }
  var max = -Infinity;
    for(var prop in myObj){
      if(myObj[prop] > max){
        max = prop;
      }
    }
   return max;
}

console.log(findMaxRepeatCountInWord('helllo'));
```

Any idea what am I missing out?

Comment: Please, add your input data for testing.

Comment: You save the `prop` as a `max`. And `prop` is the letter. Then you compare a number with a letter. Instead - you should remember the `maxLetter` and compare `myObj[prop] > myObj[maxLetter]`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a value at first and then you change `max` to a key.

I suggest to use max only for the key, with a initializing with the first element of the keys. Then iterate from the second key and check if the value is gereater then the actual max value.

```js
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word) {
  var splitWord = word.split('');
  var myObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < splitWord.length; i++) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(splitWord[i])) {
      myObj[splitWord[i]]++;
    } else {
      myObj[splitWord[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  var keys = Object.keys(myObj),       // take the keys in an array
      max = keys[0];                   // initialize with the first key
  
  for (i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {  // iterate from the second key
    if (myObj[keys[i]] > myObj[max]) { // check and
      max = keys[i];                   // update
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(findMaxRepeatCountInWord('helllo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` is one of the keys. You should compare the value of that key with the current key `prop`:

```
if(myObj[prop] > myObj[max])
//               ^^^^^^   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through each character of the text, then store the occurrence in an object

```js
var getMaxOccurence = function (text)
{
   var maxObj = {};
   // loop through each character
   for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
   {
      var char = text.charAt(i);
      // check if char is in obj
      if (!(char in maxObj))
       {
           // add occurrence
           maxObj[char] = 1;
       }
       else
       {
           // add occurrence
           maxObj[char]++;
       }
   }
 
   var max  = {
      value: 0,
      key: 0
   };
   var keys = Object.keys(maxObj);

   // here get which character contains the highest value.
   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
   {
      if (maxObj[keys[i]] > max.value)
      {
         max.value = maxObj[keys[i]];
         max.key   = keys[i];
      }
   }
   
   // return it
   return max;
};

document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = "helllo";

var result = getMaxOccurence("helllo");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result.key + " ( " + result.value + " ) ";
```

```html
Subject: <span id="subject"></span>
<br/>
Max occurence: <span id="result"></span>
```

hope that helps